# Cant use Textbox.Select(0, 0) on textbox inside scrollviewer

Tags: c#, wpf

I cant use the code that'll set the CaretIndex before the first character.

Here is my XAML Code:

```
    <Border CornerRadius="5">
        <ScrollViewer x:Name="scDetailedText" Grid.Column="0" BorderBrush="Transparent" BorderThickness="0">
            <TextBox x:Name="ucDetailedText" Text="{Binding DetailsText}" Style="{StaticResource SearchDetailsTextStyle}" BorderBrush="Transparent" BorderThickness="0"/>
        </ScrollViewer>
    </Border>
```

And here is my Backend code:

```
void ucDetailedText_IsVisibleChanged(object sender, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.NewValue.Equals(true))
    {
        ucDetailedText.Focus();
        ucDetailedText.Select(0, 0);
    }
}
```

I've narrowed it down and it seems the style prevents the code.

```
<Setter Property="Template">
    <Setter.Value>
        <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
            <TextBox x:Name="PART_EditableTextBox" MinWidth="50" Width="{Binding TextWidth}" Padding="3" BorderBrush="Transparent"
                             VerticalAlignment="Center"  Background="Transparent"
                             **This line causes the problem** ~> Text="{Binding Text, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=TemplatedParent}, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                             HorizontalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}"/>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </Setter.Value>
</Setter>
```

I've indicated below the cause, any thoughts why it happens?

Comment: works for me.. rather just setting the Focus on textbox on visiblechanged takes caret to start position.. you will need to share where exactly is this textbox

Comment: It's within 2 grids actually.

Comment: @nit i've added additional information above.

Comment: buddy why are you having Textbox template to be replaced by Textbox itself.. the issue is you are trying to set caret on the parent textbox. which in reality is not shown on the UI.. you see the textbox inside the controltemplate on UI.. and hence dont see it having the caret..

Comment: @nit so how do i get the textbox underneath?